# Integer n is passed as the second argument of List<String>.sublist(fromIndex, toIndex), but stacktrace says toIndex is n + 2 in Kotlin

Tags: java, recursion, kotlin

I'm solving a problem from Codewars : https://www.codewars.com/kata/56a5d994ac971f1ac500003e/train/kotlin
Inputs are a string array and an integer k, and output is the longest string that can be formed by taking k elements from the array consecutively and joining them to string.
Below is my code for this problem and I'm now testing it.

```
fun main() {

    val array = arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
    println(longestConsec(array, 2))

//    Combinations below don't work either
//    val array = arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4","5",  "6", "7", "8", "9")
//    println(longestConsec(array, 3))
//
//    val array = arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4","5",  "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11")
//    println(longestConsec(array, 4))

//    val array = arrayOf("1", "2", "3", "4","5",  "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13")
//    println(longestConsec(array, 5))

}

fun longestConsec(strings: Array<String>, size: Int) =
    when {
        strings.isEmpty() || size > strings.size || size <= 0 -> ""
        else -> ConsecutiveString(strings.toList(), size)
            .searchLongestConsecutiveString(0, mutableListOf())
            .maxBy { it.length } ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }

class ConsecutiveString(private val originalList: List<String>, private val size: Int) {

    tailrec fun searchLongestConsecutiveString(index: Int, acc: MutableList<String>): List<String> {
        println("start")
        return when {
            index + size >= originalList.size -> acc
            else -> {
                println(index + size)
                // *** doesn't work ***
                searchLongestConsecutiveString(
                    index + 1
                    , acc.apply { add(originalList.subList(index, index + size).joinToString("")) }
                )
                // *** doesn't work ***

                // *** works ***
//                val consecutiveString = originalList.subList(index, index + size).joinToString("")
//                searchLongestConsecutiveString(
//                    index + 1
//                    , acc.apply { add(consecutiveString) }
//                )
                // *** works ***
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException, and here is the stacktrace.

> start
>
> 2
>
> start
>
> 3
>
> start
>
> 4
>
> start
>
> 5
>
> start
>
> 6
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 8
>
> at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1010)
>
> at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:1002)
>
> at ConsecutiveString.searchLongestConsecutiveString(CodeWars.kt:37)
>
> at CodeWarsKt.longestConsec(CodeWars.kt:22)
>
> at CodeWarsKt.main(CodeWars.kt:4)
>
> at CodeWarsKt.main(CodeWars.kt)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

There are 3 interesting things here.

1. index + size, which is passed as the second argument of sublist(fromIndex, toIndex), seems to be 6 right before the line which throws the exception. The stacktrace, however, says toIndex is 8, not 6.
2. this code doesn't throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if string array's size is less than N * 2 + 3, where N is the second argument of longestConsec(strings, size)
3. No exception is thrown if a string val is prepared beforehand and added to acc (see the comment in the code above), instead of using apply() and pass the result to the method recursively

I tried without tailrec but the result was the same.

Can anyone help me figuring out what's going on here?

My environment is the folloing.

OS: Windows 10 Home

IntelliJ IDEA: 2019.2 (Community Edition) 11.0.3+12-b304.10 amd64

Kotlin: 1.3.41-release-150 (JRE 1.8.0_151-b12)

IntelliJ Kotlin plugin: 1.3.50-release-IJ2019.2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `size` inside `acc.apply`. In that scope `size` refers to the size of `acc`, not to `ConsecutiveString::size`.
Either avoid using `apply` or use the label:

```
this@ConsecutiveString.size
```

Comment: Or, I should change the name to avoid such confusion. Thank you so much!